# Execute a method after a delay

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I want to execute a method *-recognized* 2 seconds after the *-touchesEnded* method has finished execution. However, If the user touches something within these 2 seconds, the method must not be executed. A timer must again be set up to wait for 2 seconds after the *-touchesEnded* method has been executed again the next time. And so on... Hope this question is clear enough. If not, do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to coordinate this. When the event you want to start the timer is triggered use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` to schedule a function call in two seconds.

Use a Boolean variable that is global to your view controller to prevent the timer from getting set in between.

Here is a rough idea:

```
BOOL shouldRespondToTouch = YES;

- (void)touchesEnded {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(doAction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    shouldRespondToTouch = NO;
}

- (void)doAction {
    shouldRespondToTouch = YES;
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @woz , +1. However, I have found a possibly better approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void) touchesEnded {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

    }

    //define the targetmethod
    -(void) targetMethod: NSTimer * theTimer
 {
    NSLog(@\"Me is here at 1 minute delay\");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that it is really simple.

Create an ivar in view.h

```
NSDate *startDate;
```

Add the following to these methods in view.m

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
self->startDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@", startDate);
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (self->startDate) {
        NSTimeInterval ti = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self->startDate];
        NSLog(@"Time: %f", ti);
        if (ti >= 2 ) {
            NSLog(@"Yes, greater than 2 seconds !");
        }
    }
}
```

Works like a charm.